# scipy.fftpack.fft(y)は、実数部のみのパワースペクトラム値を返す？

Tags: python

[scipy.orgのscipy.fftpack.fftの仕様](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html)

を読むと

> 実数列または複素数列の離散フーリエ変換を返します。

と書いてありました。
実行してみると、引数に渡した振幅データの配列の長さ(FFTのフレームサイズ)と、返却値のパワースペクトル値の配列の長さは一致していました。

実数部と虚数部のどちらも返すのならば、対称なデータは返却できないでしょうし、
実数部と虚数部のどちらかを返すんのならば、対称データも含まれているということなのでしょう。

まだ、FFTを知り始めてから、日が浅い事もあり、その判断ができません。

実数部だけ返して、それには、対称データを含むのか？
実数部と虚数部のどちらも含み、対称データは含まないのか？

どちらでしょうか？

Comment: 僕は勘違いをしていたのかもしれません。FFTの実行結果は、実数+虚数になっており、FFTフレームサイズ配列の後ろ半分は、対称データであるということですかね？

Comment: 僕の勘違いの原因は、scipy.fftpack.fftとJavaのjtransformsというFFTライブラリの仕様の違いだと思います。jtransformsのrealForwardメソッドは、Javaには、複素数型が自作しないと無いから、FFT実行結果の配列の奇数に、複素数をdouble型として出力しているんですね。（一番の勘違いの原因は、僕に複素数の知識がないから）

Comment: もし自己解決したようであれば、スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することができ、また推奨しています。helloideaさんは参加されたばかりなのであと7時間ほど待っていただかないと自己回答できませんが、もし良ければ是非お願いいたします <(\_ \_)>

Comment: かしこまりました。